# How to model User and Profiles scenario

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, database-design

I need model a scenario with Users and associated Profiles.

**Requirement:**

A User must have a **mandatory** Personal Profile (ProfileA) also a User can **optionally** have a Business Profile (ProfileB).

A User must have only 1 Profile associated per Profile Type.

Here my ideas about the DataBase design, I would love have your opinions and thoughts specially for the use of a Nullable FK in Idea B.

If you also have alternative modeling solution please share with me. Thanks in advance.

**IDEA A:**

```
Users
------------------
UserID   PK

ProfilesA
------------------
UserID   PK FK 

ProfilesB
------------------
 UserID   PK FK
```

**IDEA B (Using Nullable FK):**

```
Users
------------------
UserID     PK
ProfileAId  NULL    FK
ProfileBId  NULL    FK

ProfilesA
------------------
ProfileAId   PK

ProfilesB
------------------
ProfileBId   PK FK
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IDEA A** won't enforce the presence of `ProfileA`.

**IDEA B** could, assuming `User.ProfileAId` is NOT NULL, but this introduces circular FKs that can only be resolved thrugh deferred constraints (which are not supported by MS SQL Server). In addition to that, you'll need a UNIQUE constraint on `User.ProfileBId` to prevent different users from sharing the same `ProfileB` (which requires additional index, and each new index poses a certain overhead, especially if you intend to use [clustering](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index)).

---

Since we are dealing with "1:1" (`User`:`ProfileA`) and "1:0 or 1" (`User`:`ProfileB`) relationships, I'd probably just put everything in the same table and then use NOT NULL vs. NULL constraints to require `ProfileA` vs. merely allow `ProfileB`.

```
User
------------------
UserID PK

ProfileARequiredField1  NOT NULL
ProfileARequiredField2  NOT NULL
ProfileARequiredField3  NOT NULL (...)
ProfileAOptionalField1  NULL
ProfileAOptionalField2  NULL
ProfileAOptionalField3  NULL (...)

ProfileBRequiredField1  NULL
ProfileBRequiredField2  NULL
ProfileBRequiredField3  NULL (...)
ProfileBOptionalField1  NULL
ProfileBOptionalField2  NULL
ProfileBOptionalField3  NULL (...)

-- For ProfileB, if one required field is present, all must be present,
-- and optional fields are allowed only if required ones are present.
CHECK (
    (
        ProfileBRequiredField1 IS NULL AND 
        ProfileBRequiredField2 IS NULL AND 
        ProfileBRequiredField3 IS NULL AND
        ProfileBOptionalField1 IS NULL AND
        ProfileBOptionalField2 IS NULL AND
        ProfileBOptionalField3 IS NULL
    )
    OR (
        ProfileBRequiredField1 IS NOT NULL AND 
        ProfileBRequiredField2 IS NOT NULL AND 
        ProfileBRequiredField3 IS NOT NULL
    )
)
```

---

Alternatively, keep the `ProfileA` fields in the `User`, but move `ProfileB` fields to a separate table, as you already did in IDEA A (there is no need for complications of IDEA B). However, NULL storage is cheap and you can use [filtered indexes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to exclude NULLs from indexes, so this is probably not worth it.

Comment: Just adding this link as reference regarding deferred integrity constraints http://www.databasedesign-resource.com/deferred-integrity-constraints.html